# Update SQLite database on disk

Tags: django, database, sqlite, heroku

My Django application (a PoC, not a final product) with a backend library uses a SQLite database - read only. The SQLite database is part of the repo and deployed to Heroku. This is working fine.

I have the requirement to allow updates to this database via the Django admin interface. This is not a Django managed database, so from Django's point of view just a binary file.

I could allow for a [`FileField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField) to handle this, overwriting the database; I guess this would work in a self-managed server, but I am on Heroku and have the constraints imposed by [Disk Backed Storage](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3#disk-backed-storage). My SQLite is not my webapp database, but limitations apply the same: I can not write to the webapp's filesystem and get any guarantee the new data will be visible by the running webapp.

I can think of alternatives, all with drawbacks:

- Put the SQLite database in another server (a "media" server), and access it remotely: this will severely impact performance. Besides, accessing SQLite databases over the network [does not seem easy](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=SqliteNetwork).
- Create a deploy script for the customer to upload the database via the usual deploy mechanisms. Since the customer is not technically fit, and I can not provide direct support, this is unfeasible.
- Move out of Heroku to a self-managed server, so I can implement this quick-and-dirty upload without complications.

Do you have another suggestion?

Comment: SQLite is the wrong tool for the job if you need what Heroku provides in terms of multiple dynos running your web app. If you don't need that AND it's too hard to switch away from SQLite, then some basic django hosting like WebFaction seems like the way to go.

Comment: @Anentropic: unfortunately the only data that the customer can handle is SQLite

Comment: the requirements aren't clear

Comment: _" allow for updates to this database via the django admin interface. Please note that this is not a django managed database, so from django's point of view, this is just a binary file"_ this suggests your alternative 1) is the way to go... have Django upload media files to S3.  the concerns about accessing SQLite over the network wouldn't apply to your app since it's not treating it as a db

Comment: @Anentropic: sure it is a database, it is just not *the* webapp database, but a database used by a library to perform obscure computations

Comment: customer then downloads new db from S3 when they need to access it

Comment: how is the backend library run though?

Comment: @Anentropic: just imported in the webapp code

Comment: you'd need a media server eg S3. web app processes could then download latest copy of db from there to their local ephemeral storage each time the backend lib code needs to run... with HTTP caching on S3 it wouldn't necessarily be downloaded every time if file hadn't changed (this should be automatic via HTTP ETags)

Answer (score 2):

PythonAnywhere.com
deploy your app and you can easily access all of your files and update them and your Sqlite3 database is going to be updated in real time without losing data.

herokuapp.com erase your Sqlite3 database every 24 hours that's why it's not preferred for Sqlite3 having web apps